# What is the missing number in this sequence?

Tags: logical-deduction

> 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-?-1-1-1

What is the missing number in this sequence?

Note: The answer is not $1$.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Could an answer be:

> 3
>
>   The sequence being the number of syllables in the letters of the alphabet, and the 23rd letter - W - has three syllables.

Comment: Incidentally, someone once pointed out to me the silliness of saying "double-u double-u double-u" (9 syllables) as an abbreviation for "world wide web" (3 syllables)

Comment: How about "double-u double-u i i" for "world war 2"?

Answer (score 17):

Could the answer be

> 0

Because

> the note says "the answer is not 1" and in computer science, "not 1" is equal to zero

Comment: Despite there being a solution, I think this is a fair point. +1

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is

> TWO

Because

> All other 25 letters of the English alphabet are single, but W is two U's